# How to pass the parameters custom view to activity class

Tags: java, android, ondraw

I have a custom view class which is `DrawView` where it extends View and has onDraw:

```
public class DrawView extends View {

    Paint paint;
    public ArrayList<Line> lines;

    public DrawView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();

    }

    public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        for(Line line : lines){
            canvas.drawLine(line.x_start, line.y_start, line.x_stop, line.y_stop, paint);
        }
    }

}
```

I want to instantiate DrawView to my `MainActivity` class which extends Activity. How would I do that? `DrawView dv= new DrawView(?)`

Btw, I would be calling `invalidate()` in `MainActivity`. I would be calling `dv.invalidate()` that's why I need to instantiate `DrawView` in my `MainActivity

Comment: have you tried `MainActivity.this` instead of `this`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can . you can instantiate your view in main activity create attributeset if you need it pass it to view constructor and done .

```
XmlPullParser parser = resources.getXml(myResouce);
 AttributeSet attributes = Xml.asAttributeSet(parser);
```

for more [info](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/AttributeSet.html) . and you can use invalidate whenever you want to refresh view .

Comment: so what would I put inside `DrawView dv= new DrawView(?)`. I just need to fill up the constructor that asks for context.

Comment: DrawView dv =new DrawView(this) pass context .

Comment: hey where did you initiate  public static ArrayList<Line> lines;
please initiated in init method first

Comment: oh yeah i forgot. ok done that. But I'm having errors on ` dv.lines.add(new Line(0, 0, 200, 200));` because I just did `DrawView dv` and did not instantiated it so my problem is really `new DrawView(?)`

Comment: i don't understand what you are trying to achieve. but create a another method instantiate your lines arraylist and invalidate view it will solve your issue so DrawView dv=new DrawView(this); dv.yournewmethod(); which contain your arraylist with lines and invalidate it and done .

Comment: ok ill try what u said. but arraylist and invalidate dont matter here. I just need to instantiate `DrawView` and `DrawView dv= new DrawView(this)` does not work. I'm finding an other solutions that I can input in `new DrawView(?)` because `this` does not work.

Comment: ok thanks, i got it working now. there was things that were not instantiated well.